# How to set the directory separator character to match the operating system?

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I am writing a qt application, with the goal of it being portable to the 3 major operating systems.

I am using QFileDialog to select a folder, and then adding it to a QListWidget. However the folder name is being returned as E:/media even though I am on Windows. I would want it to return E:\media

I could use a simple string replace, but then on Linux/Mac it would look weird to have \home\user\Documents

My code if it helps:

```
void LibrariesForm::on_addButton_clicked()
{
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select Folder"), "/", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);

    if (dir.isNull() == true)
    {
        return;
    }

    ui->librariesList->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(dir, ui->librariesList, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [QDir::toNativeSeparators()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the string just internally, you don't need to convert slashes to backslashes. Qt's classes work with linux-style pathes, too. If you want a "pretty printed" string, take Jérôme's answer. :)

Comment: Won't be very good if you have a tokenizer to split the path with the OS-Specific path seperator